# What is the Lambda Syntax to limit a subquery to the first row?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a database with Item, Tax, TaxItem and ItemPrice tables.  The relationships are quite simple with the exception of the ItemPrice table.  In the ItemPrice table there can be multiple rows for a given ItemId since Locations can override the prices specified at the Region level.  Each record must contain either a RegionId or LocationId but not both and both cannot be null.

**ItemPrice**
Id
ItemId
LocationId (nullable)
Price
RegionId (nullable)

**Item**
Id
Name

**Tax**
Id
Name
Type
Value

**TaxItem**
ItemId
TaxId

The ABP framework I am using leverages the repository pattern.  The code I current have is as follows:

```
var taxItems = _TaxItemRepository
.GetAllIncluding(ti => ti.Item, ti => ti.Tax, ti => ti.Item.ItemPrice)
.Where(ti =>
    (ti.ItemId == ItemId)
    &&
    (
        (ti.Item.ItemPrice.LocationId.HasValue && ti.Item.ItemPrice.LocationId == LocationId)
        ||
        (!ti.Item.ItemPrice.LocationId.HasValue && ti.Item.ItemPrice.RegionId == locationCacheItem.RegionId)
    )
);
```

Unfortunately it is not equivalent to the following SQL that provides the correct results:

```
declare @ItemId bigint, @LocationId bigint, @RegionId bigint
set @ItemId = 1
set @LocationId = 1
set @RegionId = 1


        select ti.TaxId as TaxId, ti.ApplyTax as ApplyTax, ip.Price, tx.Value as TaxValue, tx.SpecifyItems, tx.TaxType, tx.UseNetPrice
        from TaxItem ti 
        inner join Tax tx on tx.id = ti.TaxId
        inner join Item on ti.ItemId = Item.Id
        inner join 
        (   
            select top 1 locationId, regionId, ItemId, Price 
            from ItemPrice 
            where ItemId = @ItemId and 
            (
                (LocationId is not null and LocationId = @locationId) OR 
                (LocationId is null and RegionId = @RegionId) 
            )
        ) ip on ip.ItemId = Item.Id
```

I have two records in the ItemPrice table for ItemID 1:

```
   
LocationId  Price   RegionId
1           1.25    NULL
NULL        1.50    1
```

How do I get the Lambda expression to limit the subquery to the first row?

Comment: Have you tried using `.First()`?

Comment: Yes.  It limits the main result set to the first row, not the sub-query

Comment: There is a "select Top 1" in the sub-query in the SQL version

Comment: The most sane way then would probably be to split the C# version into two queries - do the "subquery" first, store the result of `.First()` in a temporary variable, then check against it in the "main" query.

Comment: Just a small connexe point: The concept of "first" row is dangerous if there is no sort order. It might be obvious for humans in some case (creation date, id, etc.) but, you shouldn't rely on the default returned order since it's not guaranteed to be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use not the GetAllIncluding method then, as it looks like that includes the whole collection...

Answer (score 0):

I think Abion47's comment was on the money, but I resolved the issue by upgrading to EF Core 2.1.1 and executing the SQL using the Query<TaxItemInfo>.FromSQL() method.  I think this is one of those cases where a query could not easily be expressed using Lambda notation, and was more efficiently executed using SQL.

```
var taxInfo = Context.Query<TaxItemInfo>().FromSql
  (
    $@"select ti.TaxId, ti.ApplyTax, ip.Price, tx.Value as TaxValue,   tx.SpecifyItems, tx.TaxType, tx.UseNetPrice
       from TaxItem ti 
       inner join Tax tx on tx.id = ti.TaxId 
       inner join Item on ti.ItemId = Item.Id 
       inner join 
       (
         select top 1 locationId,regionId,ItemId,Price from ItemPrice where  ItemId = {ItemId} and 
           ( 
             (LocationId is not null and LocationId = {LocationId}) OR 
             (LocationId is null and RegionId = {RegionId}) 
            ) 
        ) ip on ip.ItemId = Item.Id"
  );
```

Comment: But then what's the type of `ti.Item.ItemPrice`? The SQL query suggests that Item has multiple ItemPrices, so it should be a collection. I wonder if `ti.Item.ItemPrice.LocationId` even compiles. Also, you probably could have use LINQ after all, but a different statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't ABP framework, this is plain Linq:

```
var taxItems = from ti in context.TaxItem
               let ip = ti.Item.ItemPrice
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.LocationId == LocationId ||
                                  x.RegionId == locationCacheItem.RegionId)
               select new {
                  TaxId = ti.TaxId, 
                  ApplyTax = ti.ApplyTax, 
                  Price = ip.Price, 
                  TaxValue = ti.Tax.Value, 
                  SpecifyItems = ti.Tax.SpecifyItems, 
                  TaxType = ti.Tax.TaxType, 
                  UseNetPrice = ti.Tax.UseNetPrice
               };
```